# Array values altered in a function, but only last element of array is added

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Everything calls correctly, but only the last entry from infile shows as the first element of the array.

```
void openTxtFile(int, string [], int);  // Prototype
```

within main:

```
const int txtSize = 15;
string txtArray[txtSize] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"};

//calling function 
openTxtFile(MainOption, txtArray, txtSize);
// mainOption is an int for separate switch
// txtArray is the array, 
// txtSize is size of array.

//Function Header
void openTxtFile(int option, string *txtArray, int txtSize)

while (inFile.good())
{
    int i = 0;
    inFile >> *(txtArray + i);
    i = i + 1;
}

inFile.close();
```

Thanks for any assistance, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: You keep resetting the `i` counter inside the loop to 0.

Comment: smani - thank you.  Stupid of me.

Comment: You also shouldn't use `inFile.good()` - you will get one item too many. Write the loop as `int i = 0; while (i < txtSize && inFile >> txtArray[i]) { i = i + 1; }` instead.